# Best way to have mutiple names for disabled in CSS

Tags: css

Goal is to have two names for disabled since the class for example one checkbox and example two checkbox are the same except with how they should be disabled. Is there a way to have two types of disabled with the same functionality but different properties such as color?

Code within file.css

```
.overall-example input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background-color: #8cecbf;
    opacity: 1;
}

.overall-example input[type=checkbox]:disabled + label {
    background-color: #424242;
    opacity: 1;
}

//Is there a way to rename disable into 'disabledBlue'
.overall-example input[type=checkbox]:disabled + label {
    background-color: #4896aa;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Code within file.js

```js
//within my file.js

//example1-checkbox is disabled but with a gray background
document.getElementById('example1-checkbox').disabled = true;

//example2-checkbox is disabled with a blue background
document.getElementById('example2-checkbox').disabledBlue = true;
```

Comment: "how they are disabled" what do you mean by this? Do you mean just how they differ in appearance, or is some mechanism used to disable one and a different mechanism used to disable the other?

Comment: Just the appearance if disabled is called true in file.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:disabled
```

is a psuedo selector, they are predefined, if you want to define a specific colour for a particular disabled, you could add another class, e.g.

```
.blue
```

or

```
.disabled-blue
```

or whatever works for you

e.g.

```
.overall-example input[type=checkbox].blue:disabled + label {
    background-color: #4896aa;
    opacity: 1;
}
```